# Should i use nhibernate for a fairly small project?

Tags: nhibernate

Let me say i know NOTHING about nhibernate except its for databases. I am doing a fairly small project, should i learn nhibernate?

I guess i have 4 questions

Is using a nhibernate overkill in a small project?
What should i NOT use nhibernate for?
if i have a large project should i use nhibernate if it has very complex tables? What about simple table schemes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nhibernate is a very flexible system and can be used with simple databases or more complex ones.  The real question comes down to what your project is rather then if its big or small and how much time you want to spend setting up a good design.  If your site is just pulling a table out of database listing it on the webpage for viewing and editing. nhibernate is over kill, you simply have no need for the business objects it will create.  On the other hand if business/domain objects are the center point of your project then you can benefit from use of nhibernate.

Comment: +1 for a great overview.  I will add, though, that NHibernate makes sense if there's even a slight possibility that your application will evolve from "just pulling a table out of a database and listing it for viewing/editing".  If you start big and use less, IMO you're better off than starting small and finding you need to rewrite things to expand.

Comment: I don't disagree, but on the other hand there is YAGNI.  Just depends on how well you predict the future.

Answer (score 6):

Why not start using nhibernate on a small project?  This is a good way to learn it without the additional complication and stress of learning it on a large project.

Answer (score 5):

It certainly doesn't hurt to learn nhibernate but it might be a bit of overkill for a small project.  A small project is a great chance to learn nhibernate but if you are in a rush to get it done you're probably better off without it for now.

Comment: +1 to both your answer and Mr. Riggs'. IMHO you're both right.